# How to fetch the data from a table and use it for comparision in the script component of an SSIS Job

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS job which is getting data from an excel file and updating a database table SampleTable".

for instance consider,I am updating the following fields from the table "SampleTable" :

1. field1
2. field2
3. LastUpdated

**the field (LastUpdated) needs to be changed only if any change happens to the values of either of the fields(i.e. field1 and field2)**

the logic for updation is written in a script component.

and fetching the record value from database and comparing it with the value from the excel will be a huge performance hit.

hence i m looking for a performance friendly solution so that only once I will fetch the data from the database table (before the script execution may be) and store it temporarily somewhere .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is option where redirect updates to staging/temp table and only insert new records to original table. Then synchronize records between original and staging table by using SP/Task. It's just isolation of update and insert operations. But you will see gain in performance.

You can achieve same by Lookup transformation so that you can avail the facility of Cache Connection Manager.

[This article](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/46-SSIS-Upsert-With-Lookup-Transform.html) will provide guideline on how to use Lookup tranformation for Update/Insert and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895290.aspx) about MSDN  cache connection manager.

[Using the cache connection manager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/11/22/lookup-using-the-cache-connection-manager.aspx)

[Checking if a row exists and if it does, has it changed?](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/09/12/SSIS_3A00_-Checking-if-a-row-exists-and-if-it-does_2C00_-has-it-changed.aspx)

Have a look of [this article](http://gqbi.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/ssis-fastest-data-flow-task-item-for-transferring-data-over-the-network/) as well for performance best practices.

Comment: Thanks Vikramsinh Shinde , I have used the look up transformation and the job is done. Thanks for your help